# BigInteger Base Conversion

Tags: java, biginteger, radix

The following program should:

- Display a friendly greeting to the user
- Prompt the user for the value to convert (a String)
- Accept that String
- Prompt the user for the value of the initial base (an integer)
- Accept that integer
- Prompt the user for the desired base of the output (an integer)
- Accept that integer
- If the String is not a legal expression of a number in the initial base, display an error message and exit the program
- Convert the value represented by the String in the initial base to the desired base.
- Display the result.

My program assignment is convert a string value input by the user from the initial input base to the final input base using BigInteger. How do I convert my base 10 BigInteger bigInteger to the desired value of finalBase and return it as a String without using toString? I'm sure I'm not allowed to use StringBuilder as well as that is not thread safe.
I've been told by my professor that my code should step through the string by each character at a time.
I'm able to view the accurate base10 representation of the initial base value by using String value = "" + bigInteger; however I haven't honestly figured out where to move past that math wise

My code for reference:

```
    public static boolean isValidInt(String theValue, int theBase){
        char charParse;
        for(int i = 0; i < theValue.length(); i++){
            charParse = theValue.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(charParse) && (charParse - '0') >= theBase){
                System.out.println("Cannot have digit " + charParse + " in given base " + theBase);
                return false;
            } else if (Character.isLetter(charParse) && (charParse - 'A') + 10 >= theBase) {
                System.out.println("Cannot have character " + charParse + " in given base " + theBase);
                return false;
            } else if (!Character.isDigit(charParse) && !Character.isLetter(charParse)){
                System.out.println("Cannot have symbol " + charParse + " in given base " + theBase);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static string convertInteger(String theValue, int initialBase, int finalBase){
        if(isValidInteger(theValue, initialBase)){
            if(initialBase < 2 || initialBase > 36) {
                System.out.println("Invalid initial base");
                System.exit(1);
            } else if (finalBase < 2 || finalBase > 36) {
                System.out.println("Invalid final base");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(theValue, initialBase);
        String value = bigInteger.toString(finalBase);
        return value = value.toUpperCase();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String theValue;
        String newValue;
        int initialBase;
        int finalBase;
        System.out.println("Starting");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value to convert (a String):");
        theValue = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter value of initial base (integer):");
        initialBase = sc.nextInt();
        isValidInteger(theValue, initialBase);
        System.out.println("Enter a value for the desired output base (integer):");
        finalBase = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        newValue = convertInteger(theValue, initialBase, finalBase);
        System.out.println("New value: " + newValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So in the above code I used String value = bigInteger.toString(finalBase) to return a String representation of the base10 BigInteger in the given radix of finalBase but I'm not allowed to do that. Do i need to build another function to parse through the bigInteger string to convert individual chars to specific values?

Comment: Please edit your question and clearly explain exactly what problems you are having and where you need help.  Don't put that in the comments, put it in  your question.  Explain your task `exactly` as your professor explained it to you.  Hopefully that should not take more than a few sentences.  And please don't post links to anything.

Comment: *...I'm not allowed to use StringBuilder as well as that is not thread safe....* Your code uses two static methods that reference no external (to the functions) shared state. They are inherently thread-safe and you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: *..I'm not allowed to use StringBuilder as well as that is not thread safe...*  Then use StringBuffer.  It is a thread safe version of StringBuilder.  And you won't risk irking your professor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of converting 3932 base 10 to base 16.

```
1. 3932 / 16 = 245 w remainder 12 = hex digit C
2.  245 / 16 =  15 w remainder  5 = hex digit 5
3.   15 / 16 =   0 w remainder 15 = hex digit F

So 3932 base 10 is F5C base 16
```

Now convert base `F5C` to base `10`

```
1. set v = 0;
2.  v = v * 16 + F = 0 * 16 + 15 = 15
3.  v = v * 16 + 5 = 15 * 16 + 5 = 245
4.  v = v * 16 + C = 245 * 16 + C = 3920 + 12 = 3932
```

- You will need a string of digits (`01234...XYZ`) for the bases.
- the string will be indexed by the remainder to when going from decimal to a base
- when going from a some base to decimal you will use the base digits position in the string.  E.g. F is position 15.

The `String method` `indexOf and charAt` can help with that and `BigInteger` provides a `remainder` method.

To convert between any two bases I use decimal as an intermediary base. So from base 4 to base 18 I would convert 4 to base 10 and base 10 to base 18.  There may be other ways of doing it but imo that would be the simplest.

Check out this site for other ideas on base conversions.

Comment: bless you sweet human being

Comment: I understand what you're saying and it makes it much easier to use just the two provided methods; I'm running into trouble with trying to pass an Int remainder value of finalBase to a BigInteger holding my base10 translation of 2jtiL69M3S (User input). How would i go about recursively doing this by division and remainder inside my convertInteger method? FYI your suggestion to use the indexed string instead of having to define my own character indexing method saved me a lot of stress. I'm sorry if my description of things is convoluted it's my second year of programming lol

Comment: First, don't use recursion.  It introduces additional problems and complexities that are not needed.  All you need is a simple loop.   Here is an example of getting the remainder to index into a string.   `int r = BigInteger.valueOf(1234).remainder(BigInteger.TEN).intValue();`  Now `r` contains the value 4.  To get the next digit, `divide 1234 by 10 which will yield 123.  Then repeat. `It is essential that your read the JavaDocs for the classes you are using and see what is available to use.  And don't forget to check the sit for other information.

Comment: So did this help solve your problem?